# get index number from parent node using indexOf.call javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I have following DOM structure

```
<ul class="main-products">
  <li class="product">product</li>
  <li class="product">product</li>
  <li class="product">product</li>
<section class="banner">
<ul class="sidebar-products">
  <li class="product">product</li>
  <li class="product" id="element">product</li> // this is 5th product
  <li class="product">product</li>
```

I'm trying to get the index number(4) of the marked 5th product

```
var chl = document.querySelector('li#element')
var prt = chl.parentNode;
var idx = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(prt.children, chl);
```

Above code gives me 1 because they have different parents.
How can I modify it to include all products from other parents?

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to access the `prt.childNodes`.

```js
var chl = document.querySelector('li#element')
var prt = chl.parentNode;
const index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(prt.childNodes, chl)
console.log(index)
```

```html
<ul class="main-products">
  <li class="product">product</li>
  <li class="product">product</li>
  <li class="product">product</li>
<section class="banner">
<ul class="sidebar-products">
  <li class="product">product</li>
  <li class="product" id="element">product</li> // this is 5th product
  <li class="product">product</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all of the li.products, then find the index by testing the ids...

```js
const products = document.querySelectorAll('li.product');
const i = Array.from(products).findIndex(p => p.id === 'element');
console.log(i);
```

```html
<ul class="main-products">
  <li class="product">product</li>
  <li class="product">product</li>
  <li class="product">product</li>
<section class="banner">
<ul class="sidebar-products">
  <li class="product">product</li>
  <li class="product" id="element">product</li> // this is 5th product
  <li class="product">product</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt to get all the product using `document.querySelectorAll`, it will select all the HTML tag with the class of `product`. After that change it into an array of ids, then find the index of target id from that array.

```js
// get all the li with class product and turn it into array
const all_products = [...document.querySelectorAll('li.product')]

// convert array of li to array of id
const all_products_id = all_products.map(li => li.id)

// find the id from the array of id
console.log("The index of product with id of element = " + all_products_id.indexOf("element"))
```

```html
<ul class="main-products">
  <li class="product">product</li>
  <li class="product">product</li>
  <li class="product">product</li>
 </ul>

<section class="banner">
<ul class="sidebar-products">
  <li class="product">product</li>
  <li class="product" id="element">product</li> <!-- this is 5th product -->
  <li class="product">product</li>
</ul>
</section>
```